# Add a COUNTIFS column to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame in Python, that contains the first 2 columns from the below image: user_id, user_time.

I simply need to add the 3rd column to it, which is basically the sequence of "user_time" for each "user_id". In Excel, the formula would be:

`=COUNTIFS([user_id],[@[user_id]], [user_time], "<="&[@[user_time]])`

How would I do that in Python, please?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

Thanks [Ding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930842/add-a-countifs-column-to-a-pandas-dataframe/44930881?noredirect=1#comment76837529_44930881) for comment - if necessary use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'user_time'])
df['COUNTIFS'] = df.groupby('user_id').cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: Nice one! But I guess adding a `df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'user_time'])` would more accurately reproduce the excel function.

Comment: If you're doing `df = df.sort_values(...)` you might as well do `df.sort_values(..., inplace=True)` to avoid a copy.

Comment: Guys, you're awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Guys, anyway we can count the counts in the whole dataframe for every row? Eg: UserID 1 has 6 counts, hence 6 all rows of UserID 1 and UserID with 3.

Comment: @MubarakAbdullah - Use `df['user_id'].value_counts()`